# Potentiometer smoothing 1µF capacitor placement

Tags: arduino, capacitor, potentiometer

I am working between an Arduino and an external machine. I am using b10k potentiometers.

What's the correct placement? A, B, C or does it really matter?

[image]

There will be a ground plane in place so I am assuming C is the same as B.

Also, is 1µF enough for smoothing the potentiometer? I am using linear potentiometers and have some noise which 1µF I believe should be enough but with code I am modifying them into logarithmic when needed and have more noise than on the linear. should I use a bigger capacitor?

Comment: It should not really matter. The signal is virtually DC, a 10k pot has maximum output impedance of 2.5k when connected correctly so the time constant is 2.5 ms so cutoff is 64 Hz. But the potentiometer won't output voltage without a supply so connecting only GND and analog input won't work.

Answer (score 3):

This is a better way to do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJlwPb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This provides a time constant of 4.7 to 7.2ms (filter cutoff frequency of 22-34Hz) depending on pot position, while still maintaining a source resistance of < 10kΩ.
The time constant is R*C where R, in this case, is

R= R2 + (\$\alpha\$ - \$\alpha^2\$) * R1

Where 0 <= \$\alpha\$ < = 1 is the pot rotation. Note that it reduces to R2 at each end of pot rotation and is maximum at 0.25*R1 + R2 at the center of rotation.

Without the resistor R2 the filter becomes much less effective near either extreme of pot electrical position.

The ground trace (and Vcc trace) may or may not matter much. If you are switching a lot of current (either directly via the Arduino or by other devices mounted on the PCB) it might matter. In general separate traces running directly to the two Arduino power pins from the pot and capacitor could be better in that case. Capacitor closer to the chip is better (though possibly not noticeably in this case).

Answer (score 0):

A is better.
If you turn the poti or the cooper path is a bit longer, then you will get some noise. Self made with the poti or from the environment.

-> If you have a GND-plane, then you should connect the GND of the capacitor with this GND over a via to the GND-plane. With the solution A,B and C you create a coil and this can receive signals from the environment.
-> The capacitor should to be as close as possible to the ADC-Pin of the microcontroller.

How high is the frequency of the signal? You you can create a low-pass filter (RC-filter) for the ADC which have a higher cutoff frequency.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll use A then and place the capacitors as close as possible to the pin as well as having a via. Is it better to create a higher cutoff rather than increasing the capacitor? When using the potentiometers in reverse logarithmic usually when the potentiometer is at a quarter turn the noise is quite high

Comment: It depends on the signal you want to measure. Look at the circuit of Spehro Pefhany, if you would use a 100nF capacitor and a 47k Ohm resistor this would be the same 3dB cut off frequency, but it does not need so much current. All the current have to go over the (Poti)-Resistor R1 and so you influence the value if the current is higher. So a lower capacitor value and higher R2 value is better for accuracy.